# Result Select Very Slow in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, types, return

I'm trying to optimize this query, which when run in a procedure passing parameters (datetime or date) in the where, is very slow. However, when I execute the query outside the procedure, it returns the data quickly.

Could you give me a hand?

```
WITH PRINCIPAL AS
(
    SELECT  
        C.Empcod, C.MovEstqChv,
        SUM(NF.NFPESOLIQ) AS PESOLIQ
    FROM    
        MOV_ESTQ_DOC_COMPLEM C WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
        MOV_ESTQ M WITH (NOLOCK) ON C.EmpCod = M.EmpCod
                                 AND C.MovEstqDocComplemChv = M.MOVESTQCHV
    INNER JOIN 
        NOTA_FISCAL NF WITH (NOLOCK) ON NF.EMPCOD = C.EMPCOD
                                     AND NF.CTRLDFMODFORM = C.MovEstqDocComplemEspec
                                     AND NF.CtrlDFSerie = C.MovEstqDocComplemSerie
                                     AND NF.NFNum = MovEstqDocComplemNum
    WHERE   
        CONVERT(DATE, M.MovEstqDataEmissao) >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @dtEmissao) + 0, 0))
        AND CONVERT(DATE, M.MovEstqDataEmissao) <= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(D, -DAY(@dtEmissao), DATEADD(M, 1, @dtEmissao)))
        AND NF.NFNatOpProd = '5.905'
    GROUP BY 
        RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), M.MovEstqDataEmissao, 3),5), 
        C.MovEstqChv, C.EmpCod
), 
SECUNDARIO AS 
(
    SELECT  
        C.Empcod, C.MovEstqChv,
        CTRC.MovEstqValDoc / SUM(nfpesoliq) VALOR_FRETE_PESO
    FROM
        MOV_ESTQ_DOC_COMPLEM C WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN 
        MOV_ESTQ M WITH(NOLOCK) ON M.EMPCOD = C.EMPCOD
                                AND M.MOVESTQCHV = MovEstqDocComplemChv
    INNER JOIN 
        MOV_ESTQ M2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON M2.MovEstqDocEmpCod = C.EMPCOD
                                 AND M2.MovEstqDocEspec = MovEstqDocComplemEspec
                                 AND M2.MovEstqDocSerie = MovEstqDocComplemSerie
                                 AND RIGHT(M2.MovEstqDocNum, 6) = RIGHT(MovEstqDocComplemNum, 6)
                                 AND M2.MOVESTQCHV = C.MovEstqDocComplemChv
    LEFT JOIN 
        NOTA_FISCAL N WITH(NOLOCK) ON M2.MovEstqDocEmpCod = N.EMPCOD
                                   AND M2.MovEstqDocEspec = N.CtrlDFModForm
                                   AND M2.MovEstqDocSerie = N.CtrlDFSerie
                                   AND M2.MovEstqDocNum = N.NFNUM
    INNER JOIN 
        MOV_ESTQ CTRC WITH(NOLOCK) ON CTRC.EMPCOD = C.EMPCOD
                                   AND CTRC.MOVESTQCHV = C.MOVESTQCHV
    WHERE   
        N.NFPesoLiq > 0
        AND CONVERT(DATE, CTRC.MovEstqDataEmissao) >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @dtEmissao) + 0, 0))
        AND CONVERT(DATE, CTRC.MovEstqDataEmissao) <= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D, -DAY(@dtEmissao), DATEADD(M, 1, @dtEmissao)))
    GROUP BY 
        CTRC.MovEstqValDoc, C.MovEstqChv, C.Empcod
)
SELECT  
    @vlFreteTransferencia = SUM(SECUNDARIO.VALOR_FRETE_PESO * PRINCIPAL.PESOLIQ) / SUM(PRINCIPAL.PESOLIQ)
FROM    
    PRINCIPAL WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    SECUNDARIO WITH(NOLOCK) ON PRINCIPAL.MOVESTQCHV = SECUNDARIO.MovEstqChv
                            AND PRINCIPAL.EmpCod = SECUNDARIO.EmpCod
```

Grateful.

Comment: The problem is exactly in this query, which takes 30 seconds or more to return the result ... I believe it's the filters in the where, but I'm not sure. This select contained a subselect, which I unmasked with CTE.

Comment: [Parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) might be the issue. Add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the stored procedure to check if it runs faster.

Comment: Using functions on columns in the where prevents the use of useful indexes - that is a typical mistake. Nolock should not be used without understanding - it is not a "speed booster" without consequences. Given the names involves in your columns, I will guess that nolock might be very undesirable.